# How to check presence of the record in GAE NDB?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have two classes:

```
class User(ndb.Model): # key is user's email
    phone = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
    ...

class Question(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
    ...
```

And use the following code to add user's question to the datastore:

```
q = Question()
...
user = User.get_by_id(email)
if user:
    q.user = ndb.Key(User, email)
```

(questions could be added by unknown users)

Am I doing it correctly? Should I optimize the code somehow (use `keys_only`?) to decrease number of read/write NDB operations?

Comment: I think you are correct. Since you base on users email to be the key then you you can use also keys only. Other that that I can't see any optimization here.

Comment: @JimmyKane, when I do 'get_by_id' does not it return (=read) the whole entity?

Comment: Yes. So put over there keys only.

Comment: @JimmyKane, how should I do it? `user = User.get_by_id(email, keys_only=True)` is not valid.

Comment: Well as I see (I had some time to use the key) you cannot further optimise this apart from doing what you do. The keys_only works on queries, so It's out of the question I think.

Answer (score 0):

Would the user already be logged in? If yes, then you could store the userkey in the session and leave out the get_by_id.

Apart from that, get_by_id is pretty efficient, but if the user entity is big you should consider splitting it (because fetching a smaller entity is cheaper). Another cool thing about get_by_id is that it'll use memcache first, then the datastore if the entity wasn't in memcache. If the user is asking lots of questions the entity will probably be in memcache.